# Cost, Performance and pitfall of Invalidating JWT

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, jwt

Ive implemented JWT into my application and use Redis to store black listed tokens if I need a user's token to be invalid.

Im curios to whether its even worth using JWT at this point and not just using the typical approach of sessions.

Will it save money when in production, using AWS Elastic beanstalk for node server and their RDS?

Is it faster to use Redis over querying the DB (mysql)? My assumption is that it is quicker.

Is there a **non-avoidable** pitfall to using JWT plus Redis to invalidate tokens?

To me it seems like a decent solution and is worth it to keep JWT if the performance and costs are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of research and implementing it into my system. Redis was the way to go since I'm using JWT. Its faster than querying and reading my database than it is to check for blacklisted tokens in the database.